QGIS - Filter value relation by crossing 2 arrays
I'm working on a value-relation to filter a list based on the content of 2 fields.
The value relation is based on the field "IDC".
I want to compare the content of the field "IDC" with current_value('Cd_Hab').
The field "IDC" may contain one or multiple letters (e.g., 'A', 'A,E,G', 'J,E').
Similarly, current_value('Cd_Hab') contains values in a different format (e.g., '{"A"}', '{"E", "J"}', '{"F", "D", "E"}').
I would like to display in my list only those values where any of the values from "IDC" are found in current_value('Cd_Hab').
For example, if I have a list of values for "IDC":
'A'
'C,E'
'A,E,J'
'J,H'
'X'
'E,J'
'A,I'
And current_value('Cd_Hab') = '{"A","H"}'
These results should be filtered: 'A', 'A,E,J', 'J,H', 'A,I'
I already tried this way:
(it is working when "IDC" has only one letter:
array_contains(array_distinct(string_to_array(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(current_value('Cd_Hab'),
    '[{"}]',''),' ',''),',')), "IDC") 

Other test:
array_filter(
    string_to_array("IDC", ','),
    @element,
    array_contains(
        string_to_array(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(current_value('Cd_Hab'), '[{"}]', ''), ' ', ''), ','),
        @element
    )

)
Do you know how I could manage to get the result I want ?

You could make life easier to do a find & replace on your Cd_Hab field in two iterations to get rid of { and " so the fields have the same content. What GIS software are you using? I know it might not be relevant but there might be a tool specific to your GIS software - it doesn't hurt to hope.

I'm using QGIS, the values from current_value('Cd_Hab') are the result of a value-relation field with multi-select enabled. It adds the '{""}'

I'd ingest the related table into a python dictionary then do the replacement, that might work for you but I'd need to know how you're using the relation to be sure, all I can see here is Key, where a dictionary is a Key:Value pair.

I'm looking for an expression to filter. And I think I have what I need:
array_intersect(
array_distinct(
string_to_array("IDC", ',')
),
array_distinct(
string_to_array(
replace(
regexp_replace(
current_value('Cd_Hab'), '[{"}]', ''
),
',', ' '
),
' '
)
)
)

I think this code is working well. I forgot about array_intersect
array_intersect(
    array_distinct(
        string_to_array("IDC", ',')
    ),
    array_distinct(
        string_to_array(
            replace(
                regexp_replace(
                    current_value('Cd_Hab'), '[{"}]', ''
                ),
                ',', ' '
            ),
            ' '
        )
    )
)

